# Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io, react-native

I was working on an app with Phonegap + React.js and Socket.io. However, then React-Native got released and the native feel is amazing.

I tried getting socket.io-client working with React Native, but unfortunately without much success. I did some research and I'm getting the exact same errors as described in this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/375

The comments on the issue said to try and use the fetch API to fetch JS modules, but I think I'm doing this wrong:

```
var socketScript;    
fetch('https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js')
    .then(function(response) {
        socketScript = response._bodyText;
    }).done(function() {
        var socket = socketScript.io();
    });
```

This returns an **undefined is not a function**.

Is there any way to make socket.io-client work with React Native? Or am I looking at this the wrong way? Perhaps there are other, better suited solutions?

Comment: I think this example is very full : [Example full code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908014/11313461)

Comment: Solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052792/react-native-socket-io-how-to-connect-to-local-node-server-from-device/70952075#70952075

Comment: Please check below solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052792/react-native-socket-io-how-to-connect-to-local-node-server-from-device/70952075#70952075

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For those like me stumbling across this question looking how to integrate socket.io with react native.

Since React Native has supported websockets for a short time now, you can now set up web sockets really easily with Socket.io.  All you have to do is the following

1. npm install socket.io-client
2. first import react-native
3. assign `window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';`
4. import socket.io-client/socket.io
5. in your constructor assign `this.socket = io('localhost:3001', {jsonp: false});`

So in all it should look like this after npm installing socket.io-client:

```
import React from 'react-native';

// ... [other imports]

import './UserAgent';

import io from 'socket.io-client/socket.io';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = io('localhost:3001', {jsonp: false});
  }

  // now you can use sockets with this.socket.io(...)
  // or any other functionality within socket.io!

  ...
}
```

and then in 'UserAgent.js':

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
```

Note: because ES6 module imports are hoisted, we can't make the userAgent assignment in the same file as the react-native and socket.io imports, hence the separate module.

#### EDIT:

The above solution should work, but in the case it doesn't try create a separate socketConfig.js file. In there import anything that is needed, including `const io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');` and having `window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';` BEFORE requiring socket.io-client. Then you can connect your socket there and have all listeners in one place. Then actions or functions can be imported into the config file and execute when a listener receives data.

Comment: In my case, don't need add `window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';`, I don't know why.

Comment: +1 The `jsonp: false` configuration is important because the default value for `jsonp` causes socket.io to attempt manipulating the DOM (which doesn't exist in the react native environment).  For search posterity, the error message triggered is: "document.createElement is not a function".

Comment: We I send a callback (acknowledgement) from the client, the server receives the event and emits the callback but it doesn't run on my client .. do you know why is that?

Comment: what react version was used with this answer? Not working with v0.19

Comment: I have been using v0.19 since release and my socket still works. One thing to note is React Native now does have built in web sockets https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket if you're looking for a simple socket integration.

Comment: The `jsonp: false` bit is important. Also, there seems to be no need for the user agent bit (in fact it threw errors for me saying `document` not defined)

Comment: Setting useragent gives me error `Cannot set property userAgent of #<WorkerNavigator> which has only a getter`

Comment: for some reason, my code can connect to socket in iOS simulator but not on real iPhone. any insights?

Comment: @KelvinAliyanto, i would say to make sure you can actually reach the address you are trying to connect to from your phone. If you are running an express server or something similiar on your computer you may have to use something like ngrok to expose that port and url on your computer to your phone

Comment: You can specify explicitly transport like this: `transports: ['websocket']` then you don't need `jsonp: false` part.

Comment: For those that get an `Unable to resolve module`, I imported socket.io as follows: `import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';`

Comment: I'm not able to connect using this method. I'm not getting any error either. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This line should be: `import io from 'socket.io-client'`, without the ending `/socket.io`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the window.navigator.userAgent stuff with newer versions

Answer (score 10):

Now, if you want to use socket.io in your RN app, you must use this code:

```js
if (!window.location) {
    // App is running in simulator
    window.navigator.userAgent = 'ReactNative';
}

// This must be below your `window.navigator` hack above
const io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');
const socket = io('http://chat.feathersjs.com', {
  transports: ['websocket'] // you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected!');
});
```

Big thanks for [Eric Kryski](https://medium.com/@ekryski/how-to-actually-use-socket-io-in-react-native-39082d8d6172).

Answer (score 4):

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io(`${SOCKET_URL}:${SOCKET_PORT}`)
```

Important! `SOCKET_URL` should be your local IP address, not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

To check your local IP: 
Mac / Linux: run `ifconfig` in terminal 
Windows: run `ipconfig --all` in shell

Should be something like: `const socket = io('http://10.0.1.6:3000', {transports: ['websocket']})`

Answer (score 3):

Short of a polyfill for the WebSocket API, you can create a native module that makes use of web-sockets and send events to Javascript using `eventDispatcher`.

On the Javascript side, you would subscribe to these events using `DeviceEventEmitter.addListener`.

For more information on using native modules, see the [react-native doc on the topic](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html)

Comment: There is a polyfill for WebSockets provided in React Native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use `socket.io-client` lib, the community is complaining about compatibility issues with most versions (I did experience some). It works, but now I'm afraid to upgrade the lib because I need to verify the compatibility of the next version to my server's version and react-native's version!

It seems that a lot of people miss [react's own implementation of Websockets](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#websocket-support)! I really recommend you use this instead of `socket.io-client`. It is very similar in usage:

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');
ws.onopen = () => {  // connection opened  ws.send('something'); // send a message};
ws.onmessage = (e) => {  // a message was received  console.log(e.data);};
ws.onerror = (e) => {  // an error occurred  console.log(e.message);};
ws.onclose = (e) => {  // connection closed  console.log(e.code, e.reason);};
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit Feb 2016: React Native now supports Web Sockets so some of this advice is invalid.

You've misinterpreted the Github issue I'm afraid. In it, aackerman says:

> For this specific case you'll likely want to use the fetch API which
>   is provided by the environment.

He *doesn't* say that you should use the fetch API to grab remote JS modules. What he's suggesting is that the fetch API be used in place of the built-in Node.JS request module, which isn't available in React Native.

Let's look at your code:

```
socketScript = response._bodyText;
var socket = socketScript.io();
```

Think about this for a second - `socketScript` isn't a JavaScript object, it's a string - therefore how can you call the `io` method on it?

What you'd really need to do is parse `_bodyText` before using it (in a browser you could use `eval`), but then you'd still have the problem that while React Native has a polyfill for XHR and the fetch API, it doesn't yet have one for the WebSocket API. Unless I'm mistaken, this means you're stuck.

I suggest opening a Github issue to request a WebSocket API polyfill and ask for the thoughts of the community. Someone might have a workaround.

Comment: websocket api is already availble https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket

Comment: Solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052792/react-native-socket-io-how-to-connect-to-local-node-server-from-device/70952075#70952075

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it.

Client

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client/build/index"
io("ws://<LOCAL HOME NETWORK IP>:<PORT ON SERVER>")
```

Server

```
import express from "express"
import http from "http"
import * as SocketIO from "socket.io"

const app = express()
const server = new http.Server(app)
const io = new SocketIO.Server(server)
const port = 8000
io.on("connection", socket => {
   console.log("CONNECTIONS")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will through error

```
import io from "socket.io-client/socket.io"
```

Then just add below line....

```
import io from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io";
```

then in componenDidMount or useEffect function just add below line.Never use it under constructor of class component.

```
 var socket = io("https://localhost.com:3000", { jsonp: false });
        // client-side
        socket.on("chat_message", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Answer

In 2022 you can easily just use the latest version of socket.io-client with React Native.

`npm install socket.io-client`

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Right now there isn't a good hook based socketIO libary that I've been able to make work with RN but it's pretty straightforward to roll out your own custom hook depending on your needs. IE

```js
function useWebsocket(url) {
    const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const newSocket = io(url);
        newSocket.on('connect', ()=>setConnected(true));
        newSocket.on('disconnect', ()=>setConnected(false));
        setSocket(newSocket);
    }, [])
    return {
        connected,
        socket,
    }
}
```

Something like this can get you started. This would open a socket for each component that calls the hook, which can work well if you just need one component with one connection. Sharing the connection across components gets a little more hairy but it isn't too bad.

The `connected` state is really useful for letting your user know the status of connections and stuff like that.

But yeah, point is you can just install it and use it in your component. Don't use it in the body of your functional components