# Sending and receiving Websockets-like messages in React Native

Tags: websocket, socket.io, react-native

Is it possible to use websockets (via socket.io etc.) in a React Native app for bidirectional communication with a custom backend rather that using the supported `fetch()` with polling etc.? For example, neccessary for a chat app with React Native.

Their website does not mention an API for this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried it myself but it should be no problem to run socket.io for react-native app (it's. Socket.io is pure javascript library without any HTML/CSS dependencies I believe, so simple

> npm install socket.io --save

in your project should be enough to start using it.

Actually, it looks like someone did it before and managed to get socket.io working for react-native: https://github.com/badfortrains/wsExample

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step by step of what needs to be done to get socket.io up and running in a react native app.  Its very similar to Jarek Ptiuk's answer but has an example of what to do.

[Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io/32234446#32234446)

the example:

```
import React from 'react-native';

// ... [other imports]

window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';

import io from 'socket.io-client/socket.io';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = io('localhost:3001', {jsonp: false});
  }

  // no you can use this.socket.io(...)
  // or any other functionality within socket.io!

  ...
}
```