# How to use WebSockets (socket.io) and still be able to use chrome debugging in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to setup Websockets in a React Native application, as described here: http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/05/16/react-native-and-socket-dot-io/

```
window.navigator.userAgent = "react-native";
var io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');
```

Then in my constructor of the React Component

```
this.socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
```

This works, but breaks the Chrome debugging tools:

> Cannot set property userAgent of # which has only a getter

Having the debugger available while developing is really helpful and not having it slows me down quite a bit. Is there a way to use websockets and still be able to use the debugger?

Comment: Or, you could have my problem instead... The socket.io connection only works with the debugger attached!  No explanation for it at all.  I think the state of socket connections and RN is rather poor....  Did you end up finding anything that works?

Answer (score 0):

Do the userAgent assignment in a separate module as in this answer: [Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32234446/976092).  That fixed it for me.