# React Native Socket.io How to Connect to Local Node Server from Device

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io, react-native

I'm making a connection when pointing the `io.connect()` method towards my `localhost` in the iOS simulator, so everything is working there.

But when the `connect()` method is pointed towards my machine's LAN IP address I am unable to successfully connect to the server neither in the simulator or on the device..

I'm pretty stumped on this one right now, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved** by tunneling `localhost:3000` via [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and allowing an exception domain.

In your `info.plist` you need the following under `App Transport Security Settings`

[image]

On a mac command line run

- `brew cask install ngrok`
- `ngrok http 3000`

Then grab the outputted ngrok.io URL and use it in your `io.connect()` call and you should be set.

Comment: This also worked for me running a Rails server. Ngrok also outputs an `https` URL now, so there's no need to add the exceptions to `Info.plist` if you use that (simply `ngrok http 3000` and copy the `https` URL).

Comment: Hey I'm using `ngrok`, but still, i can't connect to the socket server, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776758/cannot-connect-to-socket-io-server-in-client-side-using-ngrok) a full details

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way -> Connection with Socket.io to Local Node Server:**

**First Step :**  you need to install socket.io into your project -

```
npm install socket.io-client
or 
yarn add socket.io-client
```

**App.js file :**

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

  const socketIOConnectionWithLocalhost = () => {
    var socket = io('localhost:3000', { jsonp: false });
    console.log('socket: ', socket);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("socket connected...");
    })

    socket.on("update", () => {
      console.log('App.js : socket event recieved:');
    });
  };
```

**Second Step :**  create **server** folder and inside it create two files: **app.js and index.html** (As per given in below image)

[image]

**Server/app.js File :**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('server - app.js - socket.id: ', socket.id);

    socket.on('update', (data) => {
        console.log('server - app.js - update:', data);
        io.emit('update', socket.id)
    });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

**index.html file :**

```
<h1>Welcome To Server</h1>

<button>UPDATE</button>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>

<script>
    var socket = io();
    var button = document.querySelector('button');
    button.onclick = function(){
        console.log('index.html - buttion click...')
        socket.emit('update');
    }
</script>
```

**Third Step :** To start node server using below command:

first go to inside server folder then enter below command ->  `cd Server`

```
node app.js
```

Then open any browser and hit localhost url -> http://localhost:3000/

*Thanks..!*