# Is React Native v0.19 version currently unusable with socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, react-native

My team have been battling to make react native play nicely with socket.io for 2 days now, without success. Is anyone currently using the most recent version of react native successfully with socket.io, or is the technology just not ready for commercial environments?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io) question, there at least used to be a way to do use socket.io with RN. If that's indeed the case, I'd suggest opening an issue in the [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues) repository, it might be a rather easy fix. I'd also making sure there are no existing [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=socket.io) related to what you're asking about before submitting an issue.

Good luck!