# React-Native socket.io no connection

Tags: socket.io, react-native

I wanted to use socket.io in my RN project. Everything was ok, until I disabled chrome debugger. Now socket.io just doesn't work, nothing happens.

This is not the same problem: [Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io)

Answer (score 0):

What's your React Native version?

In your url add `ws://` like :

```
var soc = socket('ws://192.168.1.101',{
  jsonp: false
})
```

It works fine on device with RN v0.21.0.

After I upgrade RN to 0.24.0, it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this problem. I fixed this from [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4393)

You have to initialize socket like this

```
this.socket = io('http://192.168.0.101', {jsonp: false, transports: ['websocket']});
```