# React Native with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, react-native

I'm trying to use socket.io client from react native. 
I found several answers in stack overflow including this one: [Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io) 
which suggests using socket-io client and setting the navigator.userAgent to react-native.
I tried it and it doesn't work on my android, I also found a video about this in youtube but the guy got it to work on an emulator, for me once I used remote debugging it worked as well because it was on the browser I guess.

And I found a project on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-socketio but it is still a work in progress. 
Can someone who had to deal with this issue and managed to find a solution give out some pointers?
In the end I resorted to using react native websockets on the client side and the npm ws library on the server side which works just fine but I don't have any of the fallbacks.

Comment: Well, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427929/socket-io-not-working-with-react-native-on-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you solved your problem, but for anyone facing the same issue: you don't need `navigator.userAgent` anymore to use socket.io with React Native.
Here is a little example of how you can do it now:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io('http://123.456.78.987:3200', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
})

socket.emit('dispatch', "Real time baby ")
```

Comment: Wooo, last time I tried to use socket.io with react native it didn't work. This works great now - and yeah, no need to set navigator.userAgent