# It is possible to use socket.io and ws together?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

I have a NestJS microservice using socket.io, but I need to know if it's possible to implement it in the same gateway **WebSockets** (WS). I need to send some requests at the same namespace from different clients (socket.io and ws). The actual implementation works only with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO uses Websockets but it is doing much more than it appears on first glance.
You should see it as a different protocol.

Maybe you have a chance with a workaround but it will probably get messy. I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316315/how-to-send-a-message-with-websocket-to-a-socket-io-server) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible according to the developers at socket.io. Here: https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not