# React VR - is it possible to implement real-time objects via socket.io?

Tags: react-native, socket.io, virtual-reality, react-360

I'm working on a project to showcase active RFID tracking of multiple devices in real-time. I've been looking at React VR as a possible way of showing users in remote locations the real-time positioning of the devices within a static, predefined space.

Essentially, I need to know if it is possible to use React VR with socket.io for pushing the real-time locations (x,y,z co-ords) to the frontend?

Comment: You will probally want to check out this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success using Socket.io with React-VR to receive real-time Bitcoin transaction updates.

package.json

```
socket.io-client: "^2.0.4"
```

Inside Redux store to load and store real-time data from coincap:

```
...
import io from 'socket.io-client';
...
export function loadTransactionsIntoState() {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    let socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io', { jsonp: false })
    socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
      if (tradeMsg.coin == 'BTC') dispatch(addNewTransaction(tradeMsg.trade.data))
    })
  }
}
```

I originally had this connection statement inside a React-VR component which worked just as well.