# How can I use Socket.io-stream on react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, audio-streaming

I want to use the socket stream on react-native. I searched for how to use it but I didn't find any answer. Then, I installed with `npm install socket.io-stream` in my react project folder and I gets some error. Is there another way? or Is there another package that I can use instead?(It needs to listen audio from nodejs server without using webRTC)

```
window.navigator.userAgent='react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
import ss from 'socket.io-stream';
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{jsonp: false})
    let stream = ss.createStream();
  }
}
```

Edit: I fixed error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module stream from... with `npm install stream --save` .Now I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'superCtor.prototype')`

Comment: Here you go, already answered in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408492/is-it-possible-to-combine-react-native-with-socket-io?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to include socket.io-stream not socket.io-client.

Comment: ahh!! sry read it wrong, can you pls share what error you are getting on import?

Comment: 'error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `stream` from `F:\work\MyWork\node_modules\socket.io-stream\lib\iostream.js`: Module `stream` does not exist in the Haste module map'

Comment: This is a tough one, can you try solution from this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968...also can you share your import code line?

Comment: It didn't work. I guess, react-native not support socketio stream. I added my code in the question.

Comment: Hi, can you use: constructor(props) { super(props); for your constructor? this may solve the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: Temporarily, I use webview with js. So I can use socket-stream.